# Do Roxie and her husband get back together in the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, chicago

This is a question about the movie [Chicago](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0299658/). Towards the end of the movie Amos Hart, the husband of Roxanne "Roxie" Hart, wants to get back together with the the latter. As far as I remember it correctly - she rejects him to go back and regain her fame & stardom.

Does she really leave him for good?

I read that the movie is based on the actual musical of the [same name.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(musical)) How does Amos and Roxie's story end in the musical? Is the movie's version of their story same as that of the theatrical one?

Has anyone watched* it or read the script? (Or has read anything related)

(*Apparently the musical is still being performed regularly. The latest performance was in Detroit.)

Comment: I have seen neither but according to various online sources there are no major differences. You can always check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(musical)#Synopsis

Answer (score 1):

The 2002 movie is based on a [1975 musical play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(musical)). As you can see from the libretto below, the ending is *very* similar. Amos exits, stage left.

[image]

The 1975 musical is itself based on a [1926 play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(play)) of [the same name](https://archive.org/details/chicago-1926/). Again, Amos is unceremoniously dumped after learning that there ain't no baby.

[image]

Comment: For the record, I've seen this musical performed on several occasions. Amos always walks off alone. Poor Amos